# Weird question mark icon before text in <a> element

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I'm building a custom HTML email on Visual Studio Code, and everything's working fine when previewing either with Live Server or directly on browsers (tested Safari, Opera and Chrome). However, when adding my HTML to Gmail, I'm getting this strange question mark icon inside a button (it's a link styled like a button).

[image: Button should only say "Descargar"]

There's no background image, no image inside . Just text and style.
Here's my HTML/CSS:

```html
<style type="text/css">
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400&display=swap');
.btn{
        font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        background-color: crimson;
    }
</style>

<a class="btn" href="https://google.com">Descargar</a>
```

I also tried inline CSS just in case, but I still get that question mark.
I may also say that when sending the email through putsmail.com, it shows up correctly.

Comment: Have you tried it with a system font? @import is not supported by gmail [https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-import/](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-import/)

Comment: @DvdRom yes, that's why I have the sans-serif fallback, Gmail is correctly using the default sans-serif font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure about that solution cause i cant inspect, but maybe works:

can you try like that?

```
<style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400&display=swap');
        .btn{
                font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                background-color: crimson;
            }

            .pseudo-fixer::before,
            .pseudo-fixer::after  {
                display:none !important;


            }
        </style>
        
        <a class="btn pseudo-fixer" href="https://google.com">Descargar</a>
```

Comment: Somehow that worked! I was actually making the email from zero again and this bit did get rid of the issue. Thank You!